# Playing mp3 File on android application

Tags: android

I am trying to play an mp3 music file when certain activity starts.

The "onCreate" method of the activity is the following code:

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_waiting_group_answer);
startSound();
```

}

and the "startSound" method is the following method:

```
private void startSound() { 
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;
    try {
        afd = getAssets().openFd("exploit_music.mp3");
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(),
                afd.getLength());
        // player.prepare();
        player.start();
        isPlaying = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("BUMMER");
    }
}
```

When I tried to DEBUG the code, no exception was thrown, and the file (at the assets folder) was found.
Someone has an idea what should I do to make it work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Could be that your player was not prepared when you started it.
 In debug mode, there is time for it to be prepared.
Try to call start when the player is prepared:

```
 private void startSound() { 
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;
    try {
        afd = getAssets().openFd("exploit_music.mp3");
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(),
                afd.getLength());

        player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener(){
               public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer p1){
                      p1.start();
                      isPlaying = true;

                  }       
            }
                );       
     } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("BUMMER");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, no exception was thrown, but the music is still off.
When I tried to add the line "player.prepare();" right before the try block ends, exception was thrown.
When I tried to add the line "player.start();" insted to "player.prepared();" line, no exception was thrown, but the music is still off.

any advices?

Answer (score 0):

According to [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#start%28%29), the method `prepare()` should be called before the `start()` method. In the "State Diagram" image, it is described quite clearly.

For your question, just remove the `//` before the `prepare()`, implements the `MediaPlayer.onPreparedListener` to call the `player.start()`, and use `player.setOnPreparedListener()` to set the listener.

```
private void startSound() { 
AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;
try {
    afd = getAssets().openFd("exploit_music.mp3");
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(),
            afd.getLength());
    player.prepare();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("BUMMER");
}
```

}

and in your activity

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements MediaPlayer.onPreparedListener{

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(Mediaplayer arg0){
          arg0.start();
          isPlaying = true;
    }
```

}

Comment: Hey!
I tried what you said, and to set the listener I added these lines after the player.setDataSource line:
  
   player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer p1) {

     p1.start();
     isPlaying = true;

    
}
   });

but the line: "player.prepare()" (that comes right after those lines) throws an exception.

Comment: Sorry, but could you provide the detail of the exception?

Comment: Yes :)
This is an I\O Exception, 
And the trace of it is:

04-16 17:36:15.791: W/System.err(5350): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
04-16 17:36:15.791: W/System.err(5350):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
04-16 17:36:15.801: W/System.err(5350):  at com.tutorial.menuList.WaitingGroupAnswer.startSound(WaitingGroupAnswer.java:66)
04-16 17:36:15.801: W/System.err(5350):  at com.tutorial.menuList.WaitingGroupAnswer.onCreate(WaitingGroupAnswer.java:48)
04-16 17:36:15.801: W/System.err(5350):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5200)

Comment: 04-16 17:36:15.801: W/System.err(5350):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-16 17:36:15.801: W/System.err(5350):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
04-16 17:36:15.811: W/System.err(5350):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
04-16 17:36:15.811: W/System.err(5350):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:146)
04-16 17:36:15.811: W/System.err(5350):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1240)

Comment: 04-16 17:36:15.811: W/System.err(5350):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-16 17:36:15.811: W/System.err(5350):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-16 17:36:15.811: W/System.err(5350):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5171)
04-16 17:36:15.811: W/System.err(5350):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 17:36:15.821: W/System.err(5350):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-16 17:36:15.821: W/System.err(5350):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)

Comment: 04-16 17:36:15.821: W/System.err(5350):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:564)
04-16 17:36:15.821: W/System.err(5350):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)


SORRY ABBOUT THE MESS..! I didn't found a cleaner way to do this.